# Set up multiple microphones for one recording?

Tags: recording, microphone

I need to record a conference, but I cannot buy anything (due to 3rd world constraints). I have a few crappy microphones (one in the computer, one usb based, and one that plugs into the microphone port) and I was wondering if there was any I way I could have them all on at the same time.

That is, what will I need to do to run multiple microphone out of one computer to create one recording?

I can run this on either a mac or a pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the built in to your computer / plug in to the microphone port mics use the same adc internally (this is how it is for pretty much every card), so you will have to choose one or the other, the plugged in one is probably a better bet. On the mac you can configure an [aggregate audio device](http://www.apple.com/pro/techniques/aggregateaudio/) that can combine your various inputs so a program can use them all simultaneously. With Linux, pulseaudio can combine multiple sound cards in a similar manner. As far as I know there is no way to do this on Windows, but someone will probably provide some contradictory info.

Comment: Brilliant! The aggregate audio device is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.